# Not able to see kafka messages produced from Java api in the consumer console

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I was trying to produce some messages and put into topic, and then getch the same from console consumer.

Code used :

```
import  java.util.Date;
import  java.util.Properties;
import  kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import  kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import  kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;


public  class   SimpleProducer  {
    private static  Producer<String,String> producer;
    public  SimpleProducer()    {
            Properties  props   =   new Properties();

            //  Set the broker  list    for requesting  metadata    to  find    the lead    broker
            props.put("metadata.broker.list","172.22.96.56:9092,172.22.96.56:9093,172.22.96.56:9094");

            //This  specifies   the serializer  class   for keys    
            props.put("serializer.class",   "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");

            //  1   means   the producer    receives    an  acknowledgment  once    the lead replica    
            //  has received    the data.   This    option  provides    better  durability  as  the     
            //  client  waits   until   the server  acknowledges    the request as successful.
            props.put("request.required.acks",  "1");

            ProducerConfig  config  =   new ProducerConfig(props);
            producer    =   new Producer<String,    String>(config);
    }
    public  static  void    main(String[]   args)   {
            int argsCount   =   args.length;
            if  (argsCount  ==  0   ||  argsCount   ==  1)
                    throw   new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "Please provide topic   name    and Message count   as  arguments");

            String  topic   =   (String)    args[0];
            String  count   =   (String)    args[1];
            int messageCount    =   Integer.parseInt(count);
            System.out.println("Topic   Name    -   "   +   topic);
            System.out.println("Message Count   -   "   +   messageCount);
            SimpleProducer  simpleProducer  =   new SimpleProducer();
            simpleProducer.publishMessage(topic,    messageCount);
    }
    private void    publishMessage(String   topic,  int messageCount)   {
            for (int    mCount  =   0;  mCount  <   messageCount;   mCount++)   {
                    String  runtime =   new Date().toString();
                    String  msg =   "Message    Publishing  Time    -   "   +   runtime;
                    System.out.println(msg);
                    //  Creates a   KeyedMessage    instance
                    KeyedMessage<String,    String> data    =   
                            new KeyedMessage<String,    String>(topic,  msg);

                    //  Publish the message
                    producer.send(data);
            }
            //  Close   producer    connection  with    broker.
            producer.close();
    }
```

}

OUTPUT:

> Topic  Name    -   test
>   Message Count   -   10
>   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
>   (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   Message Publishing  Time    -   Tue Feb 16 02:00:56 IST 2016
>   Message Publishing  Time    -   Tue Feb 16 02:00:56 IST 2016
>   Message Publishing  Time    -   Tue Feb 16 02:00:56 IST 2016
>   Message Publishing  Time    -   Tue Feb 16 02:00:56 IST 2016
>   Message Publishing  Time    -   Tue Feb 16 02:00:56 IST 2016
>   Message Publishing  Time    -   Tue Feb 16 02:00:56 IST 2016
>   Message Publishing  Time    -   Tue Feb 16 02:00:56 IST 2016
>   Message Publishing  Time    -   Tue Feb 16 02:00:56 IST 2016
>   Message Publishing  Time    -   Tue Feb 16 02:00:56 IST 2016
>   Message Publishing  Time    -   Tue Feb 16 02:00:56 IST 2016

from command line i supply the name of the topic as "kafkatopic" and count of the messages "10". The program runs fine without ant exception but when i try to see the messages from console, they do not appear. The topic is created.

> bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic kafkatopic --from-beginning

Can you plaease help as what went wrong!!

Comment: Could you add the command line you are executing to launch your producer ?

Comment: Ok from the stack trace you pasted, we can see that you provide the first argument as "test" `Topic Name - test`, just change it to 'kafkatopic' and it should be working fine :)

Comment: Oops !! my mistake . thanks for pointing out Lousi :)

Answer (score 0):

Two things I would like to point out:

1) You don't specify `--zookeeper` here - you should you `--bootstrap-server` argument.

2) You should see what the `server.properties` file say about `listeners` and `advertised.listener`. You should correctly point them to the brokers.

I hope this helps.